# How to decrypt GnuPG encrypted folder?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, gnupg, gpg4win

I received a file with ".pgp" extension. I decrypted it successfully, but the resulting file seems to be wrong: the sender encrypted a folder, not a single file. However, I do not see a folder after decryption - I see a strange binary file with no extension Windows 7 is not capable to open (a plain white icon in the Windows Explorer).

However, Windows must know it is a folder, because it says so when I open the "properties" window:

[image]

Any idea how to force Windows to handle this file as a folder?

Comment: I don't really know what Windows is doing here, but the file might simply prove to be a tar archive or similar. OpenPGP does not support encrypting folders out of the box, usually they're `tar`ed before. Try opening the file using 7zip or another capable archive solution.

Comment: @JensErat You were right, I installed 7zip, changed file's extension to .tar and extracted it successfully. The only problem are names of files in that folder. Some of them were not ASCII strings and those got damaged (e. g. `mezinárodní.txt` is changed to `mezinĂˇrodnĂ­­.txt`), 7zip extracted them using different encoding. Is there any way to specify encoding when extractin a TAR archive?

Comment: As my guess solved your issue, I created an answer for it. Setting up the encoding depends on the tool you're using, but probably should be possible. [Reading bug report #1284](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/1284/) you need to use the [current beta version (15.06 or newer)](http://www.7-zip.org/), where it should be resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you were shipped a `.tar` file, which is a common archive format in Linux and the UNIX world in general. Try [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or another capable archive solution to extract it.

OpenPGP does not support encrypting folders, but only single files; thus folders need to be put into an archive before encryption.